# PowerMock ClassCastException when trying to run tests with the PowerMockRunner

Tags: android, maven, powermock, robolectric

Just Adding the following dependencies to my Android maven project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And then annotating the class with @RunsWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

When executing mvn clean test, i got this weird class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl cannot be cast to org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.PowerMockJUnitRunnerDelegate
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:143)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
```

I discovered that is due to use in the same test project the robolectric test runner. But it is not applied to the same test. I mean, There are classes with the @RunsWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) and a new one with @RunsWith(PowerMockTestRunner.class). When removing all the classes that are annotated with Robolectric it works.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your class under the test have android dependency? So or it uses some directly or parent try to instantiate or call something or event mention something?

Answer (score 2):

Both [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/bytecode/AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java) and [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/FAQ) instrument code via custom classloaders. A few possible workarounds:

1. Create a new Maven submodule for the PowerMock tests.
2. I haven't tested this, but you might get it to work using the [annotation `@PowerMockIgnore`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PowerMockIgnore.html).
3. [Change the fork mode](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=21) in the surefire-plugin to `pertest`. I haven't tried this because it'll probably slow down the tests.

Comment: `@PowerMockIgnore` does not help. I had a similar issue and solved that by splitting the test class. Newly it is annotated by `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)`
and is split into two sub-classes, where one is annotated by  `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and uses power mocks and the other sub-class uses only plain JUnit tests without power mock.

Comment: Yep, @PowerMockIgnore worked well for me, I just needed to remove a package from the PowerMock classpath  and it worked just fine.